# Using SoftLayer API to configure Evault Backup (configure agent, jobs, and schedule)

Tags: api, backup, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I would like to automate, via the SoftLayer API, the configuration of an Evault Backup system -- configure the agent, create a job, set the file selection to backup, create the schedule.  I can't find any structures that seem to contain that information to create the configuration (except for creating a schedule). Does anyone know if the items needed are available using the SoftLayer API?

To try to get a better picture of related underlying structures,  I went via the GUI and created an agent, jobs, and schedule and see that the backups for that are running.  I can use the Soflayer API to then query some things -- the job details (job name/description, last run date result), agent status, but cannot seem to query the schedules or replication schedule, nor any of the Agent configuration information beyond its status.

Answer (score 0):

What I know, with the Softlayer API you only will able to get information about the Evault, to configure the device you need to use the WebCC client.