# How to automate eVault backup, are ther any APIs?

Tags: api, storage, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I want automate eVault backup without login webCC. Are there APIs can configure agent, create jobs, confiure jobs and set schedule etc for eVault backup?
From following links, they mentioned eVault backup can only do in webCC.

https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/faqs/37#822

[Using SoftLayer API to configure Evault Backup (configure agent, jobs, and schedule)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790779/using-softlayer-api-to-configure-evault-backup-configure-agent-jobs-and-sched)

But I still want confirm with you whether you support APIs to configure eVault backup now? because the above links are pasted at last year. I don't know whether you have support APIs to do eVault backup now?

Also I checked link: 
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Backup_Evault#

I don't find any job, agent related APIs in this link, the listed APIs seem only can work on existed eValut backup to retrieve the information.

So for automate eVault backup (config the agent, create a job, configure job and set schedule), what APIs I can use? or what's your suggestions for me if you don't provide APIs? Are there other solutions which I can use to automate eVault backup?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The SoftLayer API does not include functionality  to configure an Evault agent, nor create, configure or schedule a job. This is functionality available only through WebCC.

Comment: Do you have any plan to implement this kind of APIs? When will you develop SoftLayer API to support functionality to configure an Evault agent, nor create, configure or schedule a job