# Plan to provide SoftLayer APIs for eVault backup (create agent, job)?

Tags: api, storage, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

In [How to automate eVault backup, are ther any APIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38047321/how-to-automate-evault-backup-are-ther-any-apis), you mentioned currently there's no APIs support functionality to configure an Evault agent, nor create, configure or schedule a job.

I would like to know do you have any plan to provide this kind of APIs? at what time it will be ready?
How should I submit this requirement to you and add it into your release plan?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about features and feature requesting for software.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to submit a ticket to softlayer and ask them for that feature, What I know there is not any sign that they are working on such feature.